# xcode keyword syntax coloring, doesn't recognize c++ std::string

Tags: c++, xcode, syntax, stdstring

I'm using xcode to edit some c++ code---its been annoying me that xcode doesn't recognize "string" as a keyword (i.e. it doesn't give it the typical pink 'keyword color').

Does anyone know how to add it as a keyword?

Comment: why would xCode color-code it as a keyword? It is not a keyword of the language. It is just a class type like any other user-defined type (albeit a commonly used one).

Answer (score 5):

`string` is not a keyword in C++.

However if you really want it colored as a keyword for some reason, you could add it as a keyword in the file `/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Built-in languages.pblangspec`

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried adding "string" to both the C and C++ keyword lists, but 'string' is still not being colored... any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, I'll take another look and update my answer. I'll have to do it tomorrow though.